# Adding months to setMonth of javascript showing a 0

Tags: javascript, date

I'm running to an issue I'm not sure how to resolve it; so the deal is that I have a function of javascript that take the date selected from the user and depending of another selection it adds to the date 6 o 12 months, the weird thing is that when you select a date of June, and make it add the 6 months I get a return value of 0 months, and it should be 12 for December, also If you choose December and add 12 months I'm getting a 0 as a return value. So here is my code

```
        var date1 = $("#date_begin").val();
        var days= date1[0] + date1[1];
        var month= date1[3] + date1[4];
        var year= date1[6] + date1[7] + date1[8] + date1[9];

        var actualDate = new Date(year,month,days);

        actualDate.setMonth(actualDate.getMonth() + 6);//add 6 months
        $("#date_finish").val(actualDate.getDate()+"-"+actualDate.getMonth()+"-"+actualDate.getFullYear());
```

I'm printing the date directly to the text box as you can see. Also for the selection of the date in the first box I'm using the datepicker of jquery with this option selected

```
 $("#date_begin").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
```

I have been trying to fix this but I have no idea how to do it.

Hope you guys can give me a hand.

Comment: Nicholos's answer is right, but I always pass along this advice when i see javascript date questions - use a library like moment.js.  Date's in any language, but especially javascript are HARD.  There are tons of corner cases, time zones, leap years, leap seconds, etc, and maintaining it yourself is very, very error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months are indexed from `0`.
June is `5` not `6`.
What you have calculated is actually July (6) + 6 months = January (0) of the next year.

If you can get the date string into a format accepted by Date's constructor, that might be an easier way to create your date object.  Though you need to be aware that there are some differences between browsers when it comes to the formats that are accepted.

If the date comes from users, then you should use a date format that makes sense for your users, and if necessary use a library that can work with that format of date.

When the date comes from communications with the server, I like to use the same format produced by JSON.stringify (dates that look like 2015-06-09T21:42:25.816Z), and I use [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to make sure that the `new Date(string)` constructor can read strings in that format.

There is some information about parsing date strings using the `new Date(string)` constructor on [Mozilla's developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: thanks, that was the reason I was getting the 0 as a response